# The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/tesseract-android-tools/bin/classes/com' in Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, tesseract

After following these steps in this link:http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/

and adding "Tesseract-android-tools" to eclipse as a library, found this error:
The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/tesseract-android-tools/bin/classes/com'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent.

I couldn't solve this error to use the library in my App., if any one know about that error, reply quickly please.

Answer (score 5):

Delete that directory manually using a Linux terminal. It will be re-created the next time the project is built in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions for the `bin` directory of the tesseract-android-tools project. If necessary, add write permission.